# wp woocommerce category image

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I'm trying to write a php code on my index file in wordpress. I have to get the images & names of each category,
this is what I've got so far:

```
    $term = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $termid = get_term($term, 'product_cat' );
    $args = array(
        'orderby'       => 'name', 
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'    => false, 
        'child_of'      => $term, 
        'parent'        =>0
    ); 
    $subproducts = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args);
    foreach ($subproducts as $subproduct) { 
        echo $subproduct->name.'<br>';
        echo $subproduct->term_id; //get the category Id
    }
```

How do I get the category image url?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
foreach ($subproducts as $subproduct): setup_postdata($subproduct); 
    the_title();
    the_ID();
    the_post_thumbnail();
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`get_woocoomerce_term_meta`](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-get_woocommerce_term_meta.html) and get the `thumbnail_id` from it, changing the loop as below will get the job done

```
    foreach( $subproducts as $subproduct ) { 
        echo $subproduct->name.'<br>';
        echo $subproduct->term_id; //get the category Id

        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $subproduct->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'" alt="" width="762" height="365" />';
    }
```